# How to replace getTimeSinceLastSend() for DirectChannel since removal in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-integration

Methods for statistics are removed in recent version of Spring.
How could we replace the method getTimeSinceLastSend() for DirectChannel ?

Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An internal statistics has been [removed in favor Micrometer meters](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/system-management.html#metrics-management). See respective documentation how to deal with that info from Micrometer API: https://micrometer.io/docs/concepts